# Binary Operations in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, binary

I have two vectors A = [1 0 0 0 0 1] and B = [1 0 0 1 0 1]. I want to calculate the number of (1,1) (1,0) (0,1) and (0,0) from the vectors in matlab. Any idea how to go with it.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more on "calculate the number of (1,1) (1,0) (0,1) and (0,0)"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you consider reading a Matlab tutorial? You might have found an answer faster than waiting for it to appear here.

Anyway, the matlab operator for logical AND is `&`, and the one for logical negation is `~`, and both work also on `double` vectors and matrices (i.e. the default type of which A and B are when defined as in your question; all non-zero values values will be treated like `1`s).

Once you have made the required connection, `sum(x)` will give you the number of ones in `x` if x is of type `logical` or a `double` with only `0`s and `1`s.

Crude short form:

```
>> bincomb = @(x,y) sum([x&y;x&~y;~x&y;~(x|y)]');
>> bincomb(A,B)

    ans =

         2     0     1     3
```